# Erro com login do facebook em php

Tags: php, html, aplicação-web, facebook, login

Estou com erro na hora de fazer a conexão com o Facebook usando a sdk php.:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

configuração no facebook developers:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

trecho do codigo: loginfacebook.php

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Vocês podem me ajudar?

Obs: Ainda estou em faze de desenvolvimento, por tanto, uso o localhost mesmo.

Comment: Você poderia colocar na pergunta o código que está fazendo o redirecionamento para o *Facebook* ou que está abrindo a caixa de diálogo?

Comment: Dá uma olhada nisso: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24253054/1377664

Comment: Welligthon, editei e coloquei os trechos dos codigos

Comment: Aparentemente está faltando adicionar a plataforma web nas configurações: Configurações -> Básico -> Adicionar Plataforma [![config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BIrVR.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BIrVR.png) Escolha a opção "Site" [![config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kI1gy.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kI1gy.png) Configure a url e salve [![inserir a descrição da imagem aqui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kw3xs.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kw3xs.png)

Comment: O correto é colocar o código no corpo da pergunta, leia [Postar código como imagem](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5485/60376). Coloque também o código do arquivo `config.php`.